# PyInstaller build application on cross platform (Windows -> Mac)

Tags: python, windows, macos, build, pyinstaller

I do understand that I can not make a cross platfrom build. But is there any possibility that I can make it via some sort of tool? Cause I'm preparing a pandas project for my family that read their xlsx files. But they've got Mac and I've got windows and my builds with use of PyInstaller creating .exe extension files, which won't be working on Mac. Is there any site/plugin or any tool that I can use to build application cros platform?

Answer (score 1):

As a tool it can be a CI/CD pipeline, e.g. GitHub Actions which uses jobs running specific OS and publishing the binaries somewhere to download from.